# Multiplicity constraint violated VS 2010 / SQL Server / EF code-first

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, code-first, entity-framework-4.3

I am new to MVC/C# and trying to work on a small project using EF code-first which includes the following 4 classes: `Office`, `Role`, `User` and `OfficeUser`.

Problem is I am trying to use same `Role` class between `User` (define master RoleId FK Role.RoleId ) and `OfficeUser` (define OfficeRoleId for particular office FK to Role.RoleId), Also `User` and `OfficeUser` have their own relationship.

So I am trying write my authorization using `AuthorizeAttribute` for which I need to get the roles of the particular user when he/she logs into the site. And when I perform a get

```
public User GetUserRoleByUserName(string userName, string passWord)
{
   using (var context = DataContext)
   {
      return context.Users.Include("Role")
                          .Include("OfficeUsers")
                          .SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserName == userName && u.Password == passWord);
         }
     }
```

I get following error

> Multiplicity constraint violated. The role 'User_OfficeUsers_Target'
>   of the relationship 'Inventory.Repository.User_OfficeUsers' has
>   multiplicity 1 or 0..1.

Can you please tell me how can I fix this?

```
public class Office
{
       public Office()
       {
          OfficeUsers = new HashSet<OfficeUser>();
       }

      public int OfficeId { get; set; }
      public string OfficeName { get; set; }

      public virtual ICollection<OfficeUser> OfficeUsers { get; set; }
}

public class Role 
{
     public Role()
     {
         Users = new HashSet<User>();
         OfficeUsers = new HashSet<OfficeUser>();
     }

     public int RoleId { get; set; }
     public string RoleName { get; set; }
     public string Description { get; set; }

     public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
     public virtual ICollection<OfficeUser> OfficeUsers { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
     public User()
     {
         OfficeUsers = new HashSet<OfficeUser>();
     }

     public int UserId { get; set; }
     public string UserName { get; set; }
     public string Password { get; set; }
     public int RoleId { get; set; }

     public virtual ICollection<OfficeUser> OfficeUsers { get; set; }
     public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
}

public class OfficeUser
{
     public OfficeUser()
     {
     }

     public int OfficeUserId { get; set; }
     public int OfficeId { get; set; }
     public int UserId { get; set; }
     [ForeignKey("Role")]
     public int OfficeRoleId { get; set; }
     public bool Active { get; set; }

     public User User { get; set; }
     public Office Office { get; set; }
     public Role Role { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Apart from a multiple delete path problem I couldn't reproduce the error.

Answer (score 2):

This may happen if you have not put any configuration to map the relation between User and Office. here is a sample configuration class

```
public class UserConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<User>
    {
        public LocationConfiguration()
        {
            HasKey(a => a.Id);
            HasMany(user => user.OfficeUsers).WithOptional(officeuser => officeuser.User).
               HasForeignKey(officeuser => officeuser.UserId);
        }
    }
```

and add this configuration to your context as follows

```
public class YourContext : DbContext
    {

       // your DBSets and contructors, etc


        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new UserConfiguration());            
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }


    }
```

**EDIT**

try removing the data annotation  "[ForeignKey("Role")]" and then add a configuration to Role class as follows. And also add virtual keyword to Role property in OfficeUser class

```
public class RoleConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Role>
    {
        public LocationConfiguration()
        {
            HasKey(a => a.RoleId);
            HasMany(role =>role.OfficeUsers).WithOptional(officeuser => officeuser.Role).
               HasForeignKey(officeuser => officeuser.OfficeRoleId);
        }
    }
```

**EDIT**

declare the OfficeRoleId as

```
public int? OfficeRoleId { get; set; }
```

When you query for an OfficeUser you can use below method to use Lazy loading

```
YourQuery().Include(officeuser => officeuser.Role);
```

hope you understand the syntax
Regards

Comment: Thank you Jayanga,It worked using your code "modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasMany(user =>user.OfficeUsers).WithOptional(officeuser =>officeuser.User).HasForeignKey(officeuser => officeuser.UserId);" but now i get this error "Multiplicity conflicts with the referential constraint in Role 'OfficeUser_Role_Target' in relationship 'OfficeUser_Role'. Because all of the properties in the Dependent Role are non-nullable, multiplicity of the Principal Role must be '1'." using  modelb.Entity<OfficeUser>().HasOptional(c =>c.Role).WithMany(p => p.OfficeUsers).HasForeignKey(c => c.OfficeRoleId);Can u help?

Comment: Edit the answer check it and let me know

Comment: Thanks for the help I had tried and it still gives me this error "Multiplicity conflicts with the referential constraint in Role 'Role_OfficeUsers_Source' in relationship 'Role_OfficeUsers'. Because all of the properties in the Dependent Role are non-nullable, multiplicity of the Principal Role must be '1'."  modelBuilder.Entity<Role>().HasMany(role => role.OfficeUsers).WithOptional(officeuser => officeuser.Role).
              HasForeignKey(officeuser => officeuser.OfficeRoleId);

Comment: didn't work, if i try to comment previous config. that we tried betwn OfficeUsers and Users and OfficeUsers and Roles. I get the result back for admin users with data in User, User.OfficeUsers(6 count), and Users.OfficeUsers(6).Role all having data, but when I use a regular user with access to only one office only I get User, User.OfficeUsers(1 count) has data, and Users.OfficeUsers(1).Role is null thought i see value for Users.OfficeUsers(1).OfficeRoleId

Comment: Yes, that can happen because EntityFramework is using Eager loading at that time. Therefore the Role object is not filled but OfficeRoleId is filled because it is just a value (not an object). You can handle this  by using Lazy Loading instead of eager loading, will update the answer with a sample